# Can't cross-compile C program for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile C code for my Raspberry Pi 3b+ using `crostool-ng`. I'm using M1 chip Mac and trying to cross-compile my code in an Ubuntu virtual Machine(Parallels).
I compiled my own kernel using `buildroot` and created a toolchain using `crostool-ng`. `x-tools`  which is the toolchain I created located at `//home/parallels/x-tools` and I'm trying to cross-compile a simple code just prints
`Hello World` located at my Desktop. I have tried `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o deneme test.c` and got this: `deneme: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 5.12.12, with debug_info, not stripped`  file. If I send this to my target rasppi and try to run it with `./deneme`  I get this error: `-sh: ./deneme: not found` .I'm sure they are in the same directory. Now, I'm using `aarch64` but I tried with `armv71` and it didn't work either. Please ask for more information if this is not enough.

My Raspberry Pi Model: 3b+.

Host Machine: Mac m1 chip.

Raspberry Pİ ARM:AArch 64 (Little Endian)

Crosstool-ng Toolchain options:

Target Architecture: ARM

Endianess: Little endian

Bitness: 32

Operating System: Linux

Comment: Does the binary file `deneme` have execute permissions?

Comment: Does your target machine have a `/lib/ld-linux.so.3`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I find the solution. Like I said, if I run this command:`arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o deneme test.c` I get this following file `deneme: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 5.12.12, with debug_info, not stripped` as you can see this file is dynamically linked. we need to add  `-static` so we can link statically .The final solution is: `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o deneme test.c`